# What's the correct way to iterate through properties of a singleton in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, reflection, singleton, kotlin-reflect

As the title suggests, I wanted to iterate through properties of a singleton object. I tried using the kotlin-reflect as there was no other way I found currently.

```kotlin
object Test {
    const val a = "String"
    const val b = "Another String"
}

Test::class.declaredMemberProperties.forEach {
    println("${it.name}: ${it.get(Test)}")
}
```

But unfortunately this results in the following exception:

```kotlin
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Callable expects 0 arguments, but 1 were provided.
...
at com.example.MainKt.main(main.kt:25)  // same line as println statement
...
```

It seems like `get()` function has problem (`name` property resolves just fine). Is there a better approach (maybe without reflection) or some solution to access those pre-compiled constants in the singleton?

Comment: Could you explain why you want to do this?⠀ (There's no ‘correct way’, because it's not something you'd normally want to do in a strongly-typed language like Kotlin.⠀ For the particular use case of printing the object's state, you could make it a `data class` which has an automatically-generated `toString()` method.⠀ For other use cases, maybe storing the data in a `Map` instead of separate properties would fit better?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for `const val` getters, you don't need to pass the receiver object as they are compile-time constants, not runtime constants. that's why the compiler gives you this error: `Callable expects 0 arguments`. use this code it works fine for both const and non-const:

```
object Test {
    const val a = "String"
    val b = "Another String"
}

fun main() {
    Test::class.memberProperties.forEach {
        if (it.isConst) {
            println("const ${it.name}: ${it.getter.call()}")
        } else {
            println("${it.name}: ${it.getter.call(Test)}")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may not need kotlin-reflect at all for this use case.

```
object Test {
    const val a = "String"
    const val b = "Another String"
}

fun main() {
    Test::class.java
        .declaredFields
        .filter { it.name != "INSTANCE" }
        .map { "${it.name} = \"${it.get(Test)}\"" }
        .forEach(::println)
}
```

```
a = "String"
b = "Another String"
```

Link to Kotlin Playground : https://pl.kotl.in/bEgfrZk9k

Comment: Good to know this. But why was the kotlin-reflect failing to do this, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue in reflection library.

You may remove `const` modifier, or use the following workaround:

```kotlin
Test::class.members.filterIsInstance<KProperty<*>>().forEach {
    println("${it.name}: ${it.call()}")
}
```